# I'm stuck in task with loops

Tags: javascript

I try to do the task with profile lookup. It should search for prop and return his value, and if it couldn't then "No such contact" or "No such property" dependence from condition
 I don't understand why the last condition (else statement) don't perform. Here is the code.

```
var contacts = [
{
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
},
{
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
},
{
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
},
{
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
}
  ];

function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
    var i = 0;
    while (contacts[i]) {
        if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            return contacts[i][prop];

        }
        i++;
    }
    if (!contacts.firstName) {
        return "No such contact";
    }
    else {
        return "No such property";
    }

}

lookUpProfile("Akira", "address");`
```

It return "No such contact" although should return "No such property".

Comment: 'contacts' is an array and has not 'firstName'!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save a flag to denote if a name is found.
Like so:

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
    var i = 0;
    var nameflag = false;
    while (contacts[i]) {
        if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            return contacts[i][prop];
        }
        if (contacts[i].firstName == firstname)
            nameflag = true;
        i++;
    }
    if (!nameflag) {
        return "No such contact";
    }
    else {
        return "No such property";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the `contacts` and if contact with matching first name is found, you return either value of required property or "No such property". If the loop ends without returning any value, it means that contact was not found.

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
    var i = 0,
        contact;
    for(i = 0; i< contacts.length; i++) {
      contact = contacts[i];
      if(contact.firstName === firstName) {
        return contact.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? contact[prop] : "No such property";
      }
    }
    return "No such contact";
}
```

**JSBin:** https://jsbin.com/pobunavacu/edit?js,console

**Edit: (ES6 version)**

If you write code for controlled environment with no IE or Opera, you can do it even easier with ES6 features of Javascript (tested in Chrome, Firefox and NodeJS):

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
  return (contacts.find(contact => contact.firstName === firstName) || {[prop]: "No such contact"})[prop] || "No such property";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (!contacts.firstName)` Is always false

Comment: it has to be in comment instead

Answer (score 0):

This is how your function should look

```
    function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
var i = 0;
var a;
while(contacts[i]) {

if (contacts[i]["firstName"] === firstName && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop))      {
    return contacts[i][prop];

}
else if (contacts[i]["firstName"] != firstName) {
    a = "No Contact";
} else {
    a= "No property";
    return a;
}

i++;
}
return a;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your script, which returns `No such property`.

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
    var i = 0, index = 0;
    while(i < contacts.length) {
        if (contacts[i].firstName == firstName) {
            index++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (index > 0) {
        if (!contacts[index][prop]) {
            return "No such property";
        }
    } else {
        return "No such contact";
    }
}
console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "address")); //Output: No such property
console.log(lookUpProfile("John", "address")); //Output: No such contacts
```

Hope works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need flag (boolean), for your problem

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
var contactExist = false;
var i = 0;
while (contacts[i]) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName) {
        if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            return contacts[i][prop];
        } else {
            contactExist = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    i++;
}

if (!contactExist) {
    return "No such contact";
}
else {
    return "No such property";
}
```

}